# How to check windows 8 in install4j?

Tags: install4j

Util API can check window 7, vista, xp etc..
but that can't check windows 8.
How to check windows 8 in install4j??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Util.isWindows8()` will be included in install4j 5.1.3.

In the meantime, you can check if `Util.isWindows()` is true and `System.getProperty("os.version").equals("6.2")`